# Связывание таблиц ORACLE

Tags: oracle

У меня есть две таблицы **DEP_DOX** и **ADM_USER_PAYMENTS**
[image: Таблица прав просмотра платежей] и [image: Таблица закрепления подразделений с источниками доходов]

Как мне их правильно объединить, чтобы по id_user определяло какие подразделения по платежам им показывать. Заранее спасибо!
Я начал примерно так:

```
 select d.ist_dox, d.dept
from dep_dox d, adm_user_payments t
where t.id_user = :v_user_id
group by d.dept, d.ist_dox
order by d.dept
```

Comment: Наверное, добавить условия равенства полей с наименованием подразделения...

Comment: типа вот так  t.dep =d.dept

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  d.ist_dox, 
  d.dept
from 
  dep_dox d, 
  adm_user_payments t
where 
  t.id_user = :v_user_id
  and d.dept = t.dept -- Соединение таблицы
group by 
  d.dept, 
  d.ist_dox
order by d.dept;
```